# CloudContext.Clients.CreateStorageManagementClient not available?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I installed package azure management library 2, and try to call

```
        var certificate = this.GetStoreCertificate();
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CertificateCloudCredentials credentials = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.CertificateCloudCredentials("504fb4ef-3a48-4545-b7fc-b1b6cf821f48", certificate);
        var storageClient = CloudContext.Clients.CreateStorageManagementClient(credentials);
```

But this gives me a compile error with CreateStorageManagementClient function is not available.

What else should I install to create a storage account? I found this MSDN article which explains how to create a storage account, but it doesn't use any library at all and just do a http post to a Microsoft web service. I am wondering there must be some api that I can use?

[The msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh264518.aspx)

Comment: Have you installed the library from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries/?

Comment: yes, that one gives me compile error CreateStorageManagementClient function is not available

Comment: That's totally weird! I just tried in my code and didn't get any compilation error. Can you share a screenshot of all the assemblies (esp. Microsoft.WindowsAzure ones) in your project?

Comment: I am using the msdn example at the moment, maybe I did something wrong when including references

Comment: The one you included in your question? That's for the REST API.

Comment: This is actually the only thing that works for me at the moment, so will use that first and try those libraries later